# Plesk Server DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, mariadb, plesk, ubuntu-20.04

So I have just encountered a problem with my Plesk server and have been trying to figure it out. This is on a Plesk Obsidian 18.0.36 server with Ubuntu 20.04 running on MariaDB 10.3.29.

The error:

```sh
DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

And I did what most people would:

```sh
plesk repair all -y
DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Same error again, so I went on to restart the server and hope that fixed what ever the problem is with the DB.

Didn't work but at least Plesk will show an error page the domains instead of browser saying connection problem.

Went to check DB status:

```sh
systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.29 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2021-07-25 01:37:23 PDT; 11min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 1220 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1288 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1291 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR >
   Main PID: 1397 (mysqld)
     Status: "Waiting for page cleaner"
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18993)
     Memory: 79.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─1397 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

It says `Waiting for page cleaner` very interesting, no idea what that is but I believe it is a buffer cleaner triggered by the restart.

I then tried restarting and stopping the service:

```sh
$ systemctl restart mysql
^C
$ systemctl stop mysql
^C
```

The command line just became unresponsive and I have to stop it after a while... So time to went into some deep thinking and googling mode.

I did find out the solution eventually by accident, it is right below this post.

Answer (score 1):

Now the logical thing is to check what the heck is going on with the DB, the sockets are not there for obvious reasons, and the DB is not showing up on Plesk either.

I'm not sure what get into me but I went on attempting to reinstall the DB, so I do

```sh
sudo apt-get update
```

And I get a whole bunch of new errors:

```sh
Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device)
```

Which then I have a lightbulb moment and did:

```sh
df -h
```

And to my surprise the `/var` volume is full, I thought it would take a while for it to fill up but apparently, I was wrong.

```sh
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/plesk-var    50G   48G     0 100% /var
```

So I increase the volume

```sh
lvresize --resizefs --size 200GB /dev/plesk/var
```

And did the update

```sh
sudo apt-get update
```

No errors, looking good. Attempting to restart DB service:

```sh
service mariadb restart
```

All good, the page is loading, everything looks good and it looks like the whole thing has been fixed and all done.

I did run into problems again but running `plesk repair all -y` fixed them.

Just want to share this with anyone having the problem and maybe this will help, and also a doc for future reference if I encounter this again.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

The last lines of the log will indicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sudo mkdir newtmp
sudo cp -r /tmp /newtmp
sudo rm -rf /tmp
mkdir /tmp
```

You do the backup in case it asks you for a file and it does not automatically rebuild it, otherwise you will not use it, the backup is newtmp, this works if the tmp is only a folder if it is a partition it is another procedure

restart the system plesk

```
reboot
```

is all